# How to display notifications without resorting to polling on my mobile app?

Tags: flutter, mobile, notifications, webhooks

I have a java/spring/rest backend that needs to update my mobile client that something has been updated and I'm really not sure what to do for a clean, optimal implementation. The backend is your average Java/Spring backend with restful APIs, nothing fancy going on.

In the app, the user can create items that only he can see (though they're synchronized with the backend, kind of like a google doc), but he can also submit them and then the item will be manually reviewed. What I want to do is send the user the notification when the item status changes from `in_review` to `review_rejected` or `review_approved`.

I could probably poll the api responsible for user items, but since this is the kind of notifications I want to send when the app is in the background, it sounds like a terrible idea for many reasons.

I've read about webhooks but I'm new to this and it seems that it's a server-to-server solution while this is more of a server-to-client situation.

I also have some experience with MQTT but I feel like setting up a whole MQTT server for such a minor feature is out of scope.

What do you suggest I implement to solve that issue as neatly as I can ? Just in case it's relevant, the app is implemented in Flutter.
Thanks !

Comment: You may implement a backing call that verifies the presence of updates. Or find a system similar to Signalr for your backndend